# Task 'stage' not found in root project - Spring Boot not detected by Heroku buildback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, heroku

I can't deploy a Spring Boot app at Heroku due to this error in logs:

```
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * What went wrong:
   Task 'stage' not found in root project 'scraper'.

   * Try:
   Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

From [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#verify-that-your-build-file-is-set-up-correctly):

> The Gradle buildpack will run different build tasks depending on the
>   frameworks it detects in your app. For Spring Boot, it will run
>   ./gradlew build -x test. For Ratpack, it will run ./gradlew
>   installDist -x test. If no known web frameworks are detected, it will
>   run ./gradlew stage.

This means Heroku is not detecting Spring Boot and it's running as a generic framework.. The question is why. In the beginning of the logs I get:

```
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew stage
```

As techs, I have Spring Boot 2.1.1, Gradle and Kotlin 1.3.11.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle? If only the dependencies